# Avoid creating new arrays as results for numpy/scipy operations?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, optimization, scipy

For doing repeated operations in numpy/scipy, there's a lot of overhead because most operation return a new object.

For example

```
for i in range(100):
   x = A*x
```

I would like to avoid this by passing a reference to the operation, like you would in C

```
for i in range(100):
   np.dot(A,x,x_new) #x_new would now store the result of the multiplication
   x,x_new = x_new,x
```

Is there any way to do this? I would like this not for just mutiplication but all operations that return a matrix or a vector.

Comment: Check the functions's docs.  Some take an `out` parameter, especially the `ufunc` ones.  And basic operators have versions like `+=`, `*=`.  `ufuncs` also have `reduce` and `accumulate` methods to handle repeated actions.

Comment: The example code you gave using `np.dot` already does exactly this - the third argument to `np.dot` is the `out=` parameter, so `x_new` will be filled in place with the result of `np.dot(A, x)`

Comment: You might also want to consider ``np.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(A, 100), x)``.

Comment: Note that your intuition that there is "a lot of overhead" is not correct in most cases. Creating new Python objects or allocating blocks of memory is cheap compared to computations required for the matrix multiplications itself.

Answer (score 4):

See [Learning to avoid unnecessary array copies](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/#learning-to-avoid-unnecessary-array-copies) in IPython Books. From there, note e.g. these guidelines:

```
a *= b
```

will *not* produce a copy, whereas:

```
a = a * b
```

*will* produce a copy. Also, `flatten()` will copy, while `ravel()` only copies if necessary and returns a view otherwise (and thus should in general be preferred). `reshape()` also does not produce a copy, but returns a view.

Furthermore, as @hpaulj and @ali_m noted in their comments, many numpy functions support an `out` parameter, so have a look at the docs. From [numpy.dot() docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> out : ndarray, optional
>   Output argument.
>
> This must have the exact kind that would be returned if it was not used. In particular, it must have the right type, must be C-contiguous, and its dtype must be the dtype that would be returned for dot(a,b). This is a performance feature. Therefore, if these conditions are not met, an exception is raised, instead of attempting to be flexible.